# Add metadata on flash website

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, seo, metadata, keyword

I have setup a flash website for a client who has requested to add meta keywords and title for it. Is there any way to do that in Flash? The site is coded in AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add the metadata between the  tags of the html page the flash is embedded in.

Comment: Thanks, and is there a way to test that these actually work afterwards?

Comment: Yes, load the page view source.

Comment: No, I mean that the functionality works. Can this be tested using the search engines?

Answer (score 1):

This question braught me to an interesting search. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html